# VS 2013 does not build on run

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, ide

I recently upgraded from my desktop PC to a laptop. After installing VS again I have noticed that my WPF app does not build on run, although I did check my settings and it is set to always build, the only way I see my changes is when I rebuild the entire solution.

[image]

I have checked the Configuration Manager and the location where the app is building to and everything seems fine. Except for the fact that the .dll of the class library which I made a change to, was not built again.

Any ideas what this might be?

Comment: Where are you looking to check your dlls?  How do you know that they are not rebuilt - are the produced in the first place?

Comment: Guessing here, mine is identical except I have a prompt on build on the topmost dropdown. I would have verified the cmgr as you have done, then wiped the dll's, to ensure they are built and not copied from some old folders(again guessing your solution/project layout). Are you using project or binary references? If the latter, check build order of all your projects. You may also use FUSLOGVW in your  winsdk folder, to see which assemblies are loaded.

Comment: @czuroski, all projects are building to a central bin directory. I can see they are not rebuilt by checking both the date modified on the file and the output when running the application, the code changes are not reflected.

Comment: @stian I will try wiping the dll's, I am using project references and will try FUSLOGVW. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisjanLodewyks  Strange, because this would be a common problem if you were you using binary references, and having the wrong buildorder, forinstance. Let us know how it went. FUSLOGVW will tell you in detail if forinstance one your projects or dependencies is targetting an unsupported target platform (ie set to x86 while your .exe is set to AnyCPU on a x64 system or x64). FUSLOGVW is my sort of last resort when I run into startup problems like this.

Comment: After a day of being too busy to investigate further and simply clicking rebuild each time (which took ages) the problem seems to have resolved itself with no reason. When I run the application now it builds all out of date assemblies. Thank you for the suggestions.